# Use IMPORTRANGE from other sheets without having to allow access to each sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-workspace

I'm using IMPORTRANGE to count the characters within a range on another sheet.

`=LEN(IMPORTRANGE(<URL>,"Sheet1!A1:A")`

However, when I use this formula, I get a '#REF!' error saying:

> You need to connect these sheets.

With a button "Allow access":

[image: You need to connect these sheets. Allow access]

Clicking 'Allow access' works, but isn't feasible when there are thousands of sheets I need to allow access for.

I've solved this issue before with a non-GSuite by using:

```
file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.EDIT)
```

but when I try this approach on my GSuite account I get an `Access Denied: DriveApp` error when I try to call `setSharing()`:

[image: Access Denied: DriveApp]

I've tried to solve this by using `DriveApp.Access.DOMAIN` and `DOMAIN_WITH_LINK`, but both of these options require me to allow access again.

I've turned on "Sharing outside your organization" in our GSuite admin console, but I still get access denied when I try to set sharing to `ANYONE_WITH_LINK`.

Is there any way I can use `IMPORTRANGE` from another sheet with a GSuite account without having to Allow Access to each sheet?

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this out?

Comment: I'm working on this right now too, were you able to find success?